# no bounce mail in PHPlist

Tags: amazon-ses, phplist

When I send emails by phplist, I never get any bounce email report in any of above email address. Any idea why?

```
$message_envelope = 'bounce222@allheart.co.in';

$bounce_mailbox_host = 'localhost';

$bounce_mailbox_user = 'noreply@allheart.co.in';

$bounce_mailbox_password = 'MI5Topsecretpassword';

$bounce_mailbox_port = "110/pop3/notls";
```

If I use both email same in envelop and user, it starts getting error.

Everything is ok only if I get bounce emails in `noreply@allheart.co.in`, which is not working at all.

Also, when I get a bounce, it shows in SES, but not in PHPlist. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but can't figure it out.

- PHPlist verion v3.0.6
- Using amazon SES
- phplist configured on hostgator

Comment: Why don't you set up SNS notifications?

Comment: Its very expensive...

I am planning to send 50,000 unique emails / day ... 
next day 100,000
1,50,000 3rd day 
 
and so on for 1 month. 

all emails are unique and less than 0.001% are bounce...  if i go on SNS, its too much... 

All i need... phplist do that for me... just delete email whihc is bouce / complain etc...

Comment: Please help me on https://superuser.com/questions/1205929/not-able-to-send-mail-using-phplist about SMTP setting

Comment: Try sending a mail to the above address using probably a gmail/yahoo, and see if it works. This probably looks like a case of misconfigured MX records.

Answer (score 0):

If you take down the bounce address to a phplist database do one thing. Change your program code in phplist `config.php` page like this:

```
$bounce_mailbox_host     = "mail.yourdomain.com"
$bounce_mailbox_username = "bounce"
$bounce_mailbox_password = "password"
$bounce_mailbox_port     = "993/pop3/notls" instead of "110/notls"
```

And add:

```
$manually_process_bounces = 1
```

Or else create a cron job for this.